# Inject CDI bean in a Junit test script

Tags: junit, jboss, cdi

I have an application running on JBoss AS 7.1.1. This app uses some resources of CDI specification as interceptors, injection, etc. The architecture of my app is very simple with the structure below:

> **view** (xhtml and facelets)
>
> **controller** (managed beans with @Named, except in the ViewScoped)
>
> **model** (divided in two layers, service and dao)
>
> ***service*** (with @Stateless annotation, here I use an interceptor that I created to manage the transactions with database, because I use native JDBC)
>
> ***dao***

I need to create some scripts to test the application service layer, injecting the service implementation and invoking the business methods.

I believe that this architecture is very common. I'm sorry for my english.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test your full container, you probably want [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).  If you want to do Unit testing with mocks, start a standalone weld container in your test using weld-se.

```
new Weld().initialize().instance().select(YourClassName.class).get();
```

You can substitute your mock objects by using alternatives in your beans.xml.  You can also use [CDI-Unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) which simplifies the process a bit.

Comment: This CDI-Unit has other dependent libs? I tried to use it but an error ocurred. Do you know how can I configure CDI-Unit correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I did what do you recommend bblonski but this error occurs: `org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
 at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:680)
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:79)
 at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
 at org.jboss.weld.proxies.CommonDataSource$DataSource$Wrapper$-896135856$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 more...`

Comment: Did you try using the @InRequestScoped CDI-Unit annotation?  http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/#scopes  Otherwise if you want to simulate a full request cycle from your container you might have better luck with Arquillian.  Use CDI-Unit to test low level library and utility methods and Arquillian to test user requests and session data.

Comment: So...I tried to use CDI-Unit with @InRequestScoped annotation but didn't work. Arquillian didn't work because I'm not using Maven. I don't know what I have to do. I'm giving up. I already tried a lot of ways. I did a JUnit class with weld-se and I got it to inject a business component in my test script. However, when the business method is invoked, WELD-001303 error ocurred. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found an example using Arquillian with ant or gradle https://github.com/mojavelinux/arquillian-showcase/tree/master/cdi/.  There are also some notes about integrating Arquillian with other build systems here.  http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/reference/snapshot/en-US/html/build.integration.html